# Trigger a click event when dynamically generated elements are rendered Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using an API call to fetch data from database and loop through that data in HTML to make a tree structure. Conditional classes are assign while looping. I want to trigger a click event when html rendering is completed.

I have tried multiple selectors but none of them is working.

Here is my `TS` code.

```
this.reportService.getCampaignGroupList().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.campaignGroups = data;
      $('.toggle-row').trigger("click");
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-row");
      $.each(elements, function (index, value) {
      console.log(index);
      });

      $('.toggle-row').each(function () {
       console.log($(this));
      });
    },
    error => {
})
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<tr *ngFor="let cg of campaignGroups" attr.data-depth=" 
    {{cg.levelType}}" 
    class="{{cg.levelType == 0 ? 'level0: ''}}">
         <td><span class="{{cg.levelType == 0 ? 'toggle-row 
          collapse': ''}}"></span> {{cg.name}}
          </td>
          <td class="td-center">{{cg.budget | number : '1.2-2'}} 
          </td>
</tr>
```

I want to trigger a click event when api data is rendered in html. In 
       browser console when I hit `$('.toggle-row').trigger("click");` its 
       working perfectly but same code isn't working in TS.

Comment: Totally an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please explain your original goal, instead of asking for help on what you think is the solution.

Comment: Also, you should not use JQuery along with Angular, unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use jQuery in angular when you use typescript.

Second, solution as per angular page life cycle you can get call back on

ngAfterViewInit() when a page is done with rendering and binding.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {    

    ngAfterViewInit() {

    }
}
```